# How to display data only on alternate input field rows?

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm trying to display some data in a series of text boxes in a while loop. I want to fill the input fields based on a select option from the previous page. If the selected value is 25, then data should only be displayed in every fourth row. If it is 50, then data should be displayed in every alternate row, and for 100 percent, all the values will be displayed. I have marked the places where the condition of the selected value needs to be applied.

**previous.php**

```
<select class="form-control" name="select36">
<option value="100">100%</option>
<option value="50">50%</option>
<option value="25">25%</option>
```

**add.php**

```
    <?php
<!-- MYSQL QUERY -->
$sql = "select id ,code, addl_item_code_barcode, main_group, 
item_name_w_shade_category, shade_name, size , current_stock from items 
where main_group in (SELECT distinct(main_group) FROM items WHERE 
addl_item_code_barcode IN ($d)  and status='active') and status='active' 
order by  item_name_w_shade_category, size, shade_name";
$result = pg_query($db, $sql);
$counter = 1;
$i = 1;
while ($res = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { <!-- 1st loop -->
$i++;
?>    
<td> 
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE CONDITION NEEDS TO BE APPLIED FOR  SELECTED VALUE-->
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['select36'])){

<!-- FOR 100% (DISPLAY DATA IN EVERY ROW)-->  
if($_REQUEST['select36'] == 100){ 
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  size ="1" name="p36"  value =<?php 
echo $balqty; ?> disabled> <br>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['add1'])) {
$var1 = $_REQUEST['add1'];
if ($var1 > $balqty) {
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1"   style="background-color: whitesmoke;"  size ="5" 
name="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" 
value ="<?php echo $balqty ?>" onchange="calculateTotal()" readonly>
<?php } 
else {
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1" maxlength="4" size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" 
id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>"  onchange="calculateTotal()"  value ="<? 
php echo $var1 ?>">
<?php
}
?>

<?php
} else {
 $var1 = 0;
 if ($var1 > $balqty) {
 ?>
 <input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1"  style="background-color: whitesmoke;"  size ="5" name="qty_1<? 
php echo $res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" value ="<?php 
echo $balqty; ?>" onchange="calculateTotal()"  readonly>
<?php } 
else {
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1" maxlength="4" min="0"  size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo 
$res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" value ="<?php echo $var1 ? 
>" onchange="calculateTotal()"  readonly>
<?php
}
}
}
<!-- END FOR 100% (DISPLAY DATA IN EVERY ROW)--> 



<!-- FOR 50% (DISPLAY DATA IN ALTERNATE ROWS) -->                                                  
elseif($_REQUEST['select36'] == 50){
if ($i%2==0) {
 ?>

<input type="text" class="form-control"  size ="1" name="p36"  value =<?php 
echo $balqty; ?> disabled> <br>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['add1'])) {
$var1 = $_REQUEST['add1'];
if ($var1 > $balqty) {
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1"   style="background-color: whitesmoke;"  size ="5" 
name="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" 
value ="<?php echo $balqty ?>" onchange="calculateTotal()" readonly>
<?php } 
else {
?>
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1" maxlength="4" size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" 
id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>"  onchange="calculateTotal()"  value ="<? 
php echo $var1 ?>">
<?php
}
?>
<?php
} else {
$var1 = 0;
if ($var1 > $balqty) {
?>

<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1"  style="background-color: whitesmoke;"  size ="5" name="qty_1<? 
php echo $res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" value ="<?php 
echo $balqty; ?>" onchange="calculateTotal()"  readonly>
                        <?php } else {
                            ?>
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> 
saisie add1" maxlength="4" min="0"  size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo 
$res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" value ="<?php echo $var1 ? 
>" onchange="calculateTotal()"  readonly>
<?php
}
}

}
}
<!-- END FOR 50% (DISPLAY DATA IN ALTERNATE ROWS) -->  
}
?>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE CONDITION NEEDS TO END FOR THE SELECTED VALUE -->   
</td>  
<?php
$counter = $counter + 1;
}


    This is how it should look like


if(isset($_REQUEST['select36'])){
if($_REQUEST['select36'] == 25){
display data in every 4th row        <!-- KINDLY HELP ME WITH THIS LOGIC -->
}
else if($_REQUEST['select36'] == 50){
display data in alternate row
}
else if($_REQUEST['select36'] == 100){
display data in every row
}
}
```

Also kindly keep in mind that even if the data is not being displayed, empty textboxes need to be displayed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code, this is unreadable.

Comment: Hi. I have made the changes. Kindly check it now.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you whole source code.

But, I can explain you pseudo code that should work for you:

If 100% -> No need for logic, just give value to every textbox.

If 50% -> Go for even odd check

```
else if($_REQUEST['select36'] == 100) {
 if ($i%2==0) {
  $value = 'Your-Input-Value';
 }
 else {
  $value = '';
 }
```

If 25%, you have to give value to every 4th field.

This is somewhat tricky.

Hand Run:

```
0  -- No Value
1  -- No Value
2  -- No Value
**3  -- Yes Value**
4  -- No Value
5  -- No Value
6  -- No Value
**7  -- Yes Value**
8  -- No Value
9  -- No Value
10  -- No Value
**11  -- Yes Value**
12  -- No Value
```

Take a iterating variable here with current value `1`,

increment it in loop.

Shift your counter by:

```
1  -- No Value
2  -- No Value
3  -- No Value
**4  -- Yes Value**
5  -- No Value
6  -- No Value
7  -- No Value
**8  -- Yes Value**
9  -- No Value
10  -- No Value
11  -- No Value
**12  -- Yes Value**
13  -- No Value
```

Now, for every counter divisible by 4, you have value.

So, in your loop:

```
$i=1;
while (...) {
 ++$i;
 if ($i%4==0) {
  $value = 'Your-Input-Value';
 }
 else {
  $value = '';
 }
}
```

And your textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control check-change<?php echo $counter; ?> saisie add1" maxlength="4" min="0"  size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $res['id'] ?>" value ="<?php echo $value;?>" onchange="calculateTotal()" readonly>
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me what goes in $value? Is it the entire <td>? and what changes have you made in the text box that you mentioned separately?

Comment: Hi. Can you kindly tell me correct way to implement it? I wrote something for 50 using your pseudo code, but it is not working. I have updated it in the post, kindly check it.